# For incoming requests to AWS Accounts, should we use Application load balancer or Classic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For incoming requests to AWS Account, when should we use Application load balancer or Classic Load Balancer? I understand that, if we use application load balancing, we would be able to do path based routing to specific port of EC2 instance or to respective container. Is that the only criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't use a Classic load balancer for a new application. The newer Application (L7) and Network (L4) load balancers are better on many aspects. Here's the feature comparison from AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/#Product_comparisons

Comment: For every incoming requests, is it mandatory to be routed to the IP of the load balancer or it can be routed to an API gateway and make it highly available? Any specific patterns AWS offers?

Comment: AWS's elastic load balancers are already highly available. See: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/